# How to use a div to cover a scrollable area？

Tags: css

This is a simple example.

I want to fill `.fixed` with `.cover`.

But I tried some methods and it didn't work.

```css
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  overflow: auto;
}
.cover {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
  
.content {
  position: relative;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: tan;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed">
  <div class="cover"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think I can use js to get the scroll height and then set this height for `.cover`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does what you want now.

```css
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  overflow: auto;
}

.cover {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: tan;
}

}
```

```html
<div class="fixed">
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="cover"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think your current code makes it impossible to scroll.
But generally we won't know the height of .content, so we should not set the height for .cover

Comment: See updated snippet, we use height 100vh for viewport height and position sticky so it doesn't scroll with content

Answer (score 0):

add `z-index` to your `.cover`

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  overflow: auto;
}
.cover {
 position: fixed;
 left: 50px;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
 z-index: 9999;
 width: 185px;
 height: 300px;
}
  
.content {
  position: relative;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: tan;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed">
  <div class="cover"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I think we should not set height in `.cover`

Comment: I change `.cover` position to `fixed` see if it help

Answer (score 0):

Please update your properties with these and check if it resolves your issue:

```
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  overflow: auto;
}
.cover {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: tan;
}
```

Comment: As the issue with your question was with height, you can set the width as per your requirement. If my answer resolves your issue, please mark it as accepted answer.